SpotifyOAuth retrieves None Token when using Apache Airflow
I'm doing a data engineering project, which is retrieving data using the Spotify API, I'm using this function to retrieve info about my personal account:
def get_token(**kwargs):
    print(client_id, client_secret)
    sp_oauth = SpotifyOAuth(client_id = client_id,
                            client_secret=client_secret,
                            redirect_uri="http://localhost:4004/",
                            scope="user-top-read")
    token_info = sp_oauth.get_cached_token()
    if token_info:
        kwargs['ti'].xcom_push(key = 'token_data', value = token_info['access_token'])
    else:
        return None

The thing is if I run it in my local machine it works fine, it retrieves a token, but using airflow dags (in docker containers) the output is None.
I've tried using ngrok, but it didn't work. Could guide me where could be the problem? Thanks in advance.
